# valgrind complains Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c++, valgrind

I've been running my application through valgrind due to other various issues, and I keep seeing warnings about:

```
==26447== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==26447==    at 0x5C244F: int std::__int_to_char<char, unsigned long>(char*, unsigned long, char const*, std::_Ios_Fmtflags, bool) (in /home/alex/projects/Icarus/trunk/build/icarus)
==26447==    by 0x5C2BB3: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<unsigned long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, unsigned long) const (in /home/alex/projects/Icarus/trunk/build/icarus)
==26447==    by 0x5C2E1C: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, unsigned long) const (in /home/alex/projects/Icarus/trunk/build/icarus)
==26447==    by 0x5DB0BD: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<unsigned long>(unsigned long) (in /home/alex/projects/Icarus/trunk/build/icarus)
==26447==    by 0x55C9B8: ExampleProcessor::Process(std::shared_ptr<Example>) (ExampleProcessor.hpp:49)
==26447==    by 0x55D139: Controller::FIFO(std::shared_ptr<Message>) (Controller.hpp:51)
==26447==    by 0x55D7C2: TCPConnection::respond(std::string) (TCPConnection.hpp:71)
==26447==    by 0x55DC5E: TCPConnection::handle_read(boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) (TCPConnection.hpp:144)
==26447==    by 0x595CD8: void boost::_mfi::mf2<void, TCPConnection, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long>::call<boost::shared_ptr<TCPConnection>, boost::system::error_code const, unsigned long>(boost::shared_ptr<TCPConnection>&, void const*, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long&) const (mem_fn_template.hpp:271)
==26447==    by 0x591412: void boost::_mfi::mf2<void, TCPConnection, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long>::operator()<boost::shared_ptr<TCPConnection> >(boost::shared_ptr<TCPConnection>&, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) const (mem_fn_template.hpp:286)
==26447==    by 0x58A46D: void boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<TCPConnection> >, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()>::operator()<boost::_mfi::mf2<void, TCPConnection, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long const&> >(boost::_bi::type<void>, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, TCPConnection, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long>&, boost::_bi::list2<boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long const&>&, int) (bind.hpp:392)
==26447==    by 0x5812BD: void boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, TCPConnection, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<TCPConnection> >, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> >::operator()<boost::system::error_code, unsigned long>(boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long const&) (bind_template.hpp:102)
==26447==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==26447==    at 0x553EAA: ConceptGraph::makeHash() (ConceptGraph.hpp:258)
```

So, I read around a bit, and found that I can import memcheck, and ask for specific memory requests:

```
std::size_t makeHash ( )
{
  std::size_t tmp;

  for ( auto & concept : _concepts )
     tmp += concept->Hash();

  for ( auto & relation : _relations )
     tmp += relation->Hash();

  for ( auto & edge : _adjacency_list )
     tmp += std::hash<std::size_t>()( edge.first->Hash() + edge.second->Hash() );

  _hash = std::hash<std::size_t>()( tmp );

  VALGRIND_CHECK_MEM_IS_DEFINED ( _hash, sizeof(std::size_t) );

  return _hash;
}
```

The actual offending line from which the hole shebang originates from is:

```
std::stringstream hash;
hash << graph->Hash();
```

Which I know is initialized and OK.

What does that mean?

If I understand correctly, that its a warning that bytes *might* be lost ?

Is this a false positive, or am I missing something else?

Comment: `tmp` is uninitialized not `hash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::size_t makeHash ( )
{
  std::size_t tmp;

  for ( auto & concept : _concepts )
     tmp += concept->Hash();
```

You add on to `tmp`, but its initial value is unspecified.

Comment: So for any uninitialised local variable I will keep getting those warnings? Or does the same propagate?

Comment: @Alex the warning is a good one.  You can have `int tmp;` and then later `tmp=somevalue;` and that is fine.  As long as you initialize it before reading it.  `tmp+=x` is the same as `tmp = tmp + x` the `tmp` on the left of the equal is ok, the `tmp` on the right is a read of an unitialized value and is undefined behavior, don't do this.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the explanation, I understand why its useful, I'm just puzzled because I see tons of those warnings.

Comment: Why shouldn't you see lots of those warnings? You evidently have sloppy code.